# What does "Inferred provocation" mean?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

I was reading [Attack Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_dog) Wiki article, where it is said,

> An attack dog is any dog trained by a human to defend or attack a
>   territory, property or persons either on command, on sight or by
>   **inferred provocation**.

I very well know what each word means and how each is used separately. But I am having a hard time understanding how those two words come together and what they mean in this context.

I know that it probably means that if the dog is provoked, he will attack. But the use of *inferred* is confusing me here.

Comment: If your English dictionary tells you what _fry_ means, you will also know what _fried_ means. The same is true of _infer_ and _inferred_. There is no special or idiomatic meaning that is not explained in your dictionary. _Inferred provocation_ is _provocation_ that is _inferred_ (by the dog.)

Comment: Exactly. How can a dog infer? I have alway been taught that only humans infer, not animals. In Oxford dictionaries, it defines it as "Deduce or conclude (information) from evidence and reasoning rather than from explicit statements" All examples come from human beings. That why it is understandably confusing the original use.

Comment: The dictionary does not state than _only_ humans can infer. Remember: anyone can publish a dictionary. There are hundreds of them, each differs from the rest, and none of them is authoritative. This is an uncommon use of the verb, though, and a better choice might have been _perceived_.

Answer (score 2):

Even as a native speaker I don't know precisely what they mean by "inferred provocation", but I can guess that it means anything that might *provoke* the dog, such as a man holding a weapon or threatening someone in the family.

It's unclear because, presumably, the dog would have to *see* this behavior.  The article already mentions "attack on sight", but by this I assume they mean that the dog will attack the moment it **sees** a particular target, even if there is no threat.

The sentence is a good example of poor writing style.  Yes, it's more concise, but is a dog really trained to "attack a *territory* on sight?".  It's ambiguously mixing together the "attack' and "defend" options, plus "inferred provocation" is unnecessarily vague.  "Implied threat" would be better.

Comment: The subject of the attack unintentionally _implies_ a provocation to the dog, who has been trained to _infer_ provocation from a set of actions on the part of the subject. (The worst bit is _"to attack ... a persons."_ .../dons editor's hat...)